# package installed but not showing in the pycharm's available packages

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I installed the PyAutoGUI package using `pip install pyautogui`.
I can tell it's installed since I can import it using the PyCharm terminal:

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 
64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyautogui
>>> print(pyautogui)
<module 'pyautogui' from 'C:\\python\\anaconda3\\lib\\site packages\\pyautogui\\__init__.py'>
>>>
```

My problem is: When I try to add it to my project virtual environment, I can't find it on the available packages. Is there any way to add it manualy ?

P.S.: This is how I'm trying to add it:

```
File>Settings>Project>Project interpreter>install(the green plus button)>available packages>install
```

Comment: Make sure your interpreter is pointing to your `anaconda3` python env. If it is, try changing the interpreter to something else, then back to the one you actually want. If you installed the package with pip, you should not need to install it again using pycharm. It's just pycharm that is not detecting the package.

Comment: No problems when using the default interpreter, just on virtual envs, dunno why pycharm can't detect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work around this problem by uninstalling anaconda python and pycharm then reintalling pycharm and python (not anaconda), now i can add modules to my venvs no problem.

**Note:** **at first, the available packages list was empty until i added "https://pypi.python.org/" to my repositories using the manage repositories button.**

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot find PyAutoGUI on available packages (for me it is there), you can try running

```
pip install pyautogui
```

**in the pycharm terminal**. If you have already installed it in the global site-packages, pip will use the cached files in installation instead of downloading it again.

Comment: 'Requirement already satisfied: pyautogui in c:\python\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.9.38)'
The Pycharm terminal uses the global ( or shall i call it the default ) interpreter witch all packages are available. in my virtual env Still no PyAutoGUI available.

Comment: @infantry when you importing PyAutoGUI in the text editor section, does pycharm code inspection shows errors?