# PYCURL install error, exit status 10 and module not appearing when installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation, pycurl

I'm trying to install Pycurl 7.43.0.3

I'm currently using python 3.8 and pip 19.3.1

when trying to install pycurl within Pycharm I continuously get this error:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

I have tried to install it through terminal and it shows that it is installed:

pip install C:\Users\will1\Downloads\pycurl-7.43.0.3-cp38-cp38-win32.whl

Requirement already satisfied: pycurl==7.43.0.3 from file:///C:/Users/will1/Downloads/pycurl-7.43.0.3-cp38-cp38-win32.whl in c:\users\will1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (7.43.0.3)

when I then check within Pycharm's terminal it shows the same issue as above:

Collecting pycurl
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/b3/0f3979633b7890bab6098d84c84467030b807a1e2b31f5d30103af5a71ca/pycurl-7.43.0.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 10 in C:\Users\will1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h95wfib7\pycurl\

however when I then try to import the module in python it states I have no module named 'pycurl':

```
import pycurl
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycurl'

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [package installed but not showing in the pycharm's available packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918167/package-installed-but-not-showing-in-the-pycharms-available-packages)

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried those ideas and no improvements

Answer (score 0):

Visit Below Site
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl), download the whl file as per your system configuration

For example, I am a Windows 10 64 Wei, Python 3.9.0, the pycurl-7.43.0.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl download it,

Now use below command to install pycurl on your python environment
pip install pycurl-7.43.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: I am unsure if your solution is the most portable. There are more generic solutions. For example, there are configuration settings in PyCharm itself that should be able to resolve the error.